# Question about model fit indices in Confirmatory Factor Analysis

Tags: p-value, confirmatory-factor

I added data (33 observed variables, 8 latent variables, all are Likert scales) and ran CFA. Sample size is 618 respondents. A result was many fit indices (Chi-squre/DF, CFI, GFI, AGFI, NFI, NNFI, RMSEA, SRMR, and Hoelter's) are acceptable, except P-value. I modified my CFA model many times (about 11 times) by followed modification indices that suggested by a software. However, the P-value is still less than 0.05.

My question: is that acceptable if all fit indices are good, but the P-value is less than 0.05?

[image: CFA model modification progress]

Comment: Probably, yes. The reason other fit indices exist is because of problems with chi-square. But I'd be happier saying that if you actually said what the values were.

Comment: Also, when you ask a question, check and double check the numbers. Presumably you mean 0.05, not 0.5.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The fit indices were Chi-squre/DF, CFI, GFI, AGFI, NFI, NNFI, RMSEA, SRMR, and Hoelter's.

Comment: Ignore chi-square/df, GFI, AGFI and Hoelters, and then tell me the actual values of the others.

Comment: I uploaded my fit values as a picture file above, but this one, I've tried to push p-value to pass 0.05.

Comment: You present 25 models. Which model do you want to evaluate? It's better not to upload text as an image - people can't use a screen reader, change font, etc. Also, what's the sample size?

Comment: I think I should evaluate the last one, which was:

P-value 0.0556
Chi-Square 436.197
df 149
Chi/df 2.927496644
RMSEA 0.0558
GFI 0.937
AGFI 0.902
RMR 0.162
SRMR 0.0319
NFI 0.961
NNFI 0.963
RFI 0.944
Critical N 272.688
CFI 0.974
IFI 0.974
Smallest Std. Residual  -2.29
Largest Std. Residual 5.216

and My sample size is 618.

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment about which fit indices to ignore?

Answer (score -1):

If your p-value is 0.05, that means that assuming the null hypothesis is true, then the probability of you getting the above results is 5%. So effectively, a lower p-value is better.

So I wouldn't worry about your p-value, as it looks good.
Simultaneously your CFI, GFI and AGFI are increasing, while RMSEA is decreasing, which are all good signs.

You have to find that optimum region where the p-value is still low, while the CFI,GFI and AGFI are reasonably high, and it looks like you have reached it.

Comment: This is the opposite of true. Lower p-value indicates that the model is unlikely to have generated the data.